# How to add list of tables in Rmarkdown ? [R]

Tags: r, r-markdown

Does any1 has any idea how to add them when I use syntax like this?

```
---
title: " "
author: " "
date: "2014"
output: 
   pdf_document:
      includes:
         in_header: header.tex
      highlight: pygments
      toc: true
      toc_depth: 3
      number_sections: true
      keep_tex: true
---
```

And `header.tex` is:
But I think does not change that I have problems with NO list of tables like in LaTeX.

```
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\bfseries \small{text}}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\bfseries \small{author}}
```

Thanks for any answers :)
On Rmarkdown [documentation](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html) I wasn't able to find a clue...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are basically writing LaTeX, so just put

```
\listoftables
```

where you want the list of tables to appear.

Here's a screenie of my Rmd in RStudio and the generated PDF:

[image: Markup/PDF screenshot]

Comment: Thanks ! I didnt expect it's so simple